# Magento 1.7 product images issue

Tags: magento-1.7, product-images, image-upload

I am facing a strange problem with my magento 1.7 installation. 
If I upload images for any product, save and check the product on the frontend, facing this error

> a:5:{i:0;s:1203:"Invalid method
>   Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Media::isGalleryImageVisible(Array (
>   [0] => Varien_Object Object ( [_data:protected] => Array ( [value_id]
>   => 8 [file] => /1/0/10425097_688517641274252_8269930450739102673_n.jpg [label] => [position] => 1 [disabled] => 0 [label_default] =>
>   [position_default] => 1 [disabled_default] => 0

Product works fine if no image is attached.

Any thoughts what is causing the issue?

Comment: If you are getting any error code, then check your error in `var/report/[ERROR_CODE]` from there you can get actual error

Comment: a:5:{i:0;s:1203:"Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Media::isGalleryImageVisible(Array
(
    [0] => Varien_Object Object
        (
            [_data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [value_id] => 8
                    [file] => /1/0/10425097_688517641274252_8269930450739102673_n.jpg
                    [label] => 
                    [position] => 1
                    [disabled] => 0
                    [label_default] => 
                    [position_default] => 1
                    [disabled_default] => 0
   and other lines of code

Answer (score 1):

`Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Media::isGalleryImageVisible` is a method in 1.9.1 and later

Probably you have used gallery plugin for compatible with Magento 1.9.1 and you are currently in Magento 1.7

in your theme file: `app/design/frontend/YOUR_THEME/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml` comment out the condition where `isGalleryImageVisible` method is calling. Something like this:

```
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
        <?php //if ($this->isGalleryImageVisible($_image)): ?>
        <img id="image-<?php echo $i; ?>"
             class="gallery-image"
             src="<?php echo $this->getGalleryImageUrl($_image); ?>"
             data-zoom-image="<?php echo  $this->getGalleryImageUrl($_image); ?>" />
        <?php //endif; ?>
    <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
```

This function would be calling 2 times in same file, make sure you remove both.

Comment: I haven't installed any plugin yet just relying on the default features.

Comment: May be your theme is using gallery plugin from Magento 1.9, because isGalleryVisible function is from magento 1.9.1

Comment: Let me update my answer

Comment: are you using rwd theme?

Comment: Please check updated answer

Comment: bravo bro ... it worked. But it is only showing one image which i have set up as base image. I have uploaded 3 images but only one is showing (base image).

Comment: Please paste your code in different question and send me link here, I will check and will try to resolve it

Comment: Please mark this answer correct, so that it will help others too in future :)